# Typescript void returns

Tags: typescript, substitution

This thing works:

```
type voidReturn = (myparam: string) => void;
let voidFunction: voidReturn;
voidFunction = (myparam) => myparam.length;
```

This however doesn't:

```
function voidReturnError(myparam: string): void {
  return myparam.length;
  // Error: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'void'.
}
```

Why is this happening?
Aren't these two supposed to be one and the same?

Comment: [Why are functions returning non-void assignable to function returning void?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-returning-non-void-assignable-to-function-returning-void)

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware. However this seems to only apply in arrow functions. In the second example, the function declaration does indeed return an error.

Comment: @stratis — No. It has nothing to do with arrow functions. In the first example the **type** is a function which returns void (meaning "The return value of whatever is assigned here will never be looked at" while in the second you are saying "This function in particular has a void return value" and then contradicting that in the same function.

Comment: @stratis well, you *assign* an arrow function to the variable. Hence the relevance of the FAQ entry which talks about assignability. The regular function declaration you don't assign. You directly declare it returns void and yet it doesn't. It's much more likely to be an error, than if you say you'd eventually get a void function and assign a non-void function to it. The FAQ describes why you'd not want to fail the type check then.

Comment: Right. Then why can't you just do: `let myvar: void; myvar = 1;` ?

Comment: See the answer to the linked question for more information